# Spark when/otherwise can't return different StructType

Tags: scala, apache-spark, case

I have the following Spark code, it depending on condition tries to parse json, each time with a different schema:

```
df.withColumn("message",
        when($"foo".isNull, from_json($"value".cast("string"), schema1))
          .otherwise(from_json($"value".cast("string"), schema2)
        )
      )
```

it is failing with `THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type;`

My aim is to apply different schemas depending on the condition.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible.

`from_json` converts a string value into a specific `StructType` according to the provided schema, which will be the datatype of the new created column.
Since the `when` condition is evaluated for every row, it can't return different StructTypes as a dataframe's column can't be defined with multiple datatypes.

I would recommend you to create 2 different columns, one for the condition `$foo.isNull` and another for `$foo.isNotNull`.